# How to combine dataframes with different columns without merge?

Tags: r, dataframe

**Desired result**: I would like to combine dataframes such that columns in DF2 that are in DF1 are row-binded to DF1; columns that are in DF1 but NOT in DF2 have nrow(DF2) zeros added to them; and columns that are in DF2 but NOT in DF1 have nrow(DF1) zeros prepended to them and then those columns are cbinded onto the DF.

**What I've tried**: I've tried using ncol, nrow, and matrix to generate the parts of the final df, but I'm running into issues, such as corner cases where the second DF only has one column and ncol(DF) returns NULL, for ex.

**Template for desired result**:

For ex, if I have these two DFs:

```
> DF_dummy_1
  a b c e
1 1 a f u
2 2 b g v
3 3 c h w
4 4 d i x
5 5 e j y

> DF_dummy_2
  a b d
1 1 p k
2 2 q l
3 3 r m
4 4 s n
5 5 t o
```

I would like to end up with

```
> DF_final
    a b c e d
1   1 a f u 0
2   2 b g v 0
3   3 c h w 0
4   4 d i x 0
5   5 e j y 0
6   1 p 0 0 k
7   2 q 0 0 l
8   3 r 0 0 m
9   4 s 0 0 n
10  5 t 0 0 o
```

---

Code to generate this ex:

```
DF_dummy_1 <- data.frame("a" = seq(1:5), "b" = letters[1:5], "c" = letters[6:10], "e" = letters[21:25])
DF_dummy_2 <- data.frame("a" = seq(6:10), "b" = letters[16:20], "d" = letters[11:15])
DF_final <- data.frame("a" = seq(1:10), "b" = c(letters[1:5],letters[16:20]),
                       "c" = c(letters[6:10], rep("0",5)), 
                       "e" = c(letters[21:25], rep("0",5)),
                       "d" = c(rep("0",5), letters[11:15]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` option after placing the datasets in a list.  (Just for convenience, named the datasets as 'df1', 'df2'), By default, 'NAs' will occupy the missing rows, which can be later replaced to 0.

```
library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE)[,
         lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))]
#    a b c e d
# 1: 1 a f u 0
# 2: 2 b g v 0
# 3: 3 c h w 0
# 4: 4 d i x 0
# 5: 5 e j y 0
# 6: 1 p 0 0 k
# 7: 2 q 0 0 l
# 8: 3 r 0 0 m
# 9: 4 s 0 0 n
#10: 5 t 0 0 o
```

Based on the 'data' updated in the post, some of the columns are 'factors'.  You could use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame(..)` to avoid the character columns getting converted to `factors`.  Considering these are `factor` columns

```
  rbindlist(list(DF_dummy_1, DF_dummy_2), fill=TRUE)[, 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(as.character(x), is.na(x), 0))]
 #   a b c e d
 #1: 1 a f u 0
 #2: 2 b g v 0
 #3: 3 c h w 0
 #4: 4 d i x 0
 #5: 5 e j y 0
 #6: 1 p 0 0 k
 #7: 2 q 0 0 l
 #8: 3 r 0 0 m
 #9: 4 s 0 0 n
#10: 5 t 0 0 o
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this: item 2 has 3 columns,  inconsistent with item 1 which has 4 columns

Comment: @goldisfine I am using `data.table_1.9.5` the devel version, which version of data.table do you have?

Comment: Ah, got it. Is there an easy way to update to 1.9.5?

Comment: @goldisfine  Please check this link https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: Hey dude, thank you so much! This is an awesome package that I hadn't run across, but I'll definitely dive into!

Comment: One quick question: I am getting a warning when I try to replace the NAs. 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated. Any thoughts on how to fix this. Not sure what the issue is after reading lapply. I can't just use DF[is.na(DF)] <- 0 either: that leads to the same error.

Comment: @goldisfine Based on my second code, I am not getting any warnings with `factor` columns.  But, the safest would be to create the dataset with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame`